# For the Horizon Walker ranger's Distant Strike feature, can you teleport, then move, then attack? Or must the attack immediately follow the teleport?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, attack, ranger, teleportation

I have yet to find clarification on when exactly the teleportation from the [Horizon Walker ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#HorizonWalker)'s [Distant Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#DistantStrike-726) feature must occur relative to the actual attack. The description of the feature says (XGtE, p. 42; emphasis mine):

> [...] you can teleport up to 10 ft. **before each attack** to an unoccupied space you can see.

Does that mean you can teleport at any time before you attack? Or must the attack land the moment you appear? (In other words: Does "before" imply immediately prior to each attack, or at any time during your turn before/between each attack?)

For melee, this makes a huge difference, since all 3 creatures need to be very close together if you can't move between teleporting and attacking.

Comment: @Non-novelist When adding a system tag to a question that does not explicitly specify the system, we prefer that you leave a brief comment explaining the reasoning and asking OP to confirm. This case was pretty obvious to any D&D 5e expert, but it's still good to ask. See here for more detailed guidance: [What should I do when a question does not specify the game system being used?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11722)

Comment: Thanks all, I'll remember to tag it next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Rules as written, read strictly, indicate that you can move after teleporting and before attacking.

As you've demonstrated, the text for this ability doesn't state "immediately before attacking", so you can indeed teleport, moving then attacking as you would would for any turn where you take the Attack action.

There is clear precedent for the requirement of the word "immediately". Compare this to other features in this [D&D Beyond search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=Immediately%20before&f=backgrounds,classes,feats,races&c=characters), each of which clearly indicate either "immediately before" or "immediately after" their respective actions.

*Doesn't this allow you to change your mind after teleporting?*

Not really. D&D 5e rules don't provision well for promises. Imagine that a Horizon Walker teleports into range of an enemy which has taken the Ready Action in anticipation of this, attacking as soon as the Horizon Walker finishes teleporting. If the attack kills the Horizon Walker, then they can't attack and they've broken their "promise" to attack after teleporting. Most people would agree that this scenario can play out, else it would imply that you could see the future with Distant Strike and use it as an "undo" button.

Under this interpretation, it follows that you simply need the *intent* to attack in order to use the ability. So long as, to the best of your ability, you follow up on your promise to attack after teleporting with Distant Strike, then you can use it.

#### The rules probably don't expect you to do this.

The example above is a little tedious, and I think it's safe to say that the designers probably intend for you to attack immediately after teleporting. It's much easier to assume that they made a mistake than to assume the implied existence of a promise framework.

Comment: I dunno mate, it feels like you should declare the attack, then teleport as part of that. For example a very gratuitous application of your ruling would have a player saying "I have 3 attacks so I'm going to teleport 30ft and then start attacking". Yeah, technically it's "before" the attacks, but I doubt that's correct.

Comment: @Non-novelist it feels wrong because it's almost certainly not what the designers intended. Nonetheless it's the plain English reading of the rules.

Comment: I'm not super convinced, but I'd have to go and compare the wording with other features. It feels like almost kid level logic, like "did you brush your teeth before bed?" "yep I brushed them last week" 

Comment: @Non-novelist fair point haha. At the very least, before "each attack" seems to imply that the teleportation instances can't be contiguous and need to be broken up with attacks. Still doesn't mean that you can't move before attacking, however.

Comment: One of the biggest problems I have with the strict interpretation is that it has an enormous gap in practicallity between a melee ranger and a bow wielding on. Because of the inherent ranged attack, you can still follow the strict interpretation (your enemies can even be hundreds of feet apart). If you're melee, not only do enemies neet to be close, they have to be organized in particular ways to get all 3 attacks in (assuming they're all larger than medium size). That said, it feels like the intention of this skill is to change "attack" to "teleport attack".

Comment: @Exempt_Medic makes a pretty strong argument for allowing movent after the attack since monk's Flurry of Blows specifies the last attack must occur **immediately** while Distant Stike does not

Comment: @Andrendire I like to imagine a Horizon Walker teleporting 10 feet instead of moving for their entire life and counting every time, then subtracting 1 every time they attack or are interupted. The first time they go to teleport and can't??? That means they have that X attacks left in their life and will die before the last hits. Horizon Walker the teleporting death clock.

Comment: Umm... "If the attack kills the Horizon Walker, then they can't attack and they've broken their promise to attack after teleporting." At that point, I think what the Horizon Walker intended to do is kind of moot - they're dead.

Comment: In a situation where taking the Attack action, required for Distant Strike to apply ("When you take the Attack action, ..."), only allows you to make a single attack (e.g. you're affected by Slow), the text seems to me to prevent moving between the teleport and the attack. Taking the Attack action immediately triggers the first (and only) attack, which allows you to teleport up to 10 ft before it. You can't pause between the declaration of intent to take the Attack action and making the attack to do something else.

Comment: Features like Extra Attack and Two-Weapon Fighting complicate things a little because they do allow you to move between attacks (though not between declaring that you're taking the Attack action and the first attack), but for the sake of consistency (and simplicity) - and based on the name of the feature, Distant Strike - I would rule that you teleport as part of taking each attack, and can't ever teleport -> move -> attack.

Answer (score 5):

### No clarification is necessary. You can always move in between attacks on your turn.

The text of the ability gives all relevant information.

> At 11th level, you gain the ability to pass between the planes in a blink of an eye. When you use the Attack action, you can teleport up to 10 feet before each attack to an unoccupied space you can see.
>
> If you attack at least two different creatures with the action, you can make one additional attack with it against a third creature.

This is the text of Distant Strike.  All it says is that you can (not must) teleport up to 10 feet before each attack taken as part of the Attack action, and grants an extra attack as part of any Attack action where you attack at least two different creatures (whether you teleport or no), although that attack must be against a third creature.  Whether you can attack 3 creatures and then get an extra attack targeting any of the three (making the other two the 'two' mentioned) is slightly unclear, but whether you can move normally during your Attack action is not.

Nothing in this ability changes that you can move before and between attacks taken as part of an Attack action.  That is the normal rule - and this ability does not change it at all or even mention it.

Ergo, you can still move between attacks.  Being able to teleport does not somehow remove your ability to walk - you are not even required to teleport to use this ability, it says 'can'.  There is nothing stopping the Horizon Walker from *walking* between targets for this ability, or walking some of the way and then teleporting the remaining distance.

In a broader sense, this is a pretty out there assumption (that an ability allowing you to teleport means you can no longer walk) so i'd potentially make sure you are not assuming similarly nonexistent rules about other abilities or text in the game.

Comment: I'm focusing on the "before each attack" aspect. Does the teleport need to immediately precede the attack or can it be any time before the attack? 


Scenario 1: If I'm hasted, 35 base movement, can I teleport 10 feet, then run 50 feet, attack, teleport 10 feet, run 20 feet then attack? 


It's a huge difference from scenario 2: running 50 feet, teleporting 10 feet then attacking, running 20 feet then teleporting 10 feet and attacking because there is an attack of opportunity in scenario 2. 


I'm not worried about the 3 creature attack issue - other posts handle that.

Comment: @ak_bio Compare this with the Monk's Flurry of Blows: "***Immediately* after you take the Attack action** on your turn [...]", the Flitterstep Eidolon's Flitterstep: "The eidolon magically teleports [...] If it makes an attack ***immediately* after teleporting** [...]", and the Charger feat: "If you move at least 10 feet in a straight line ***immediately* before taking this bonus action** [...]" Given these wordings, I'd say this interpretation is correct because Distant Strike does *not* use the word "immediately".

Comment: @Exempt-Medic that makes sense. I've played a lot of 5e but I've admittedly avoided the monk so I know why I've never seen this ;).